# Binomial Model Strike Price Assumption

Tags: options, arbitrage, binomial-tree, no-arbitrage-theory

Let us have the standard single-period binomial pricing model, and denote the up and down states of the underlying by $S_u$,$S_d$ respectively. Let us say we have a call option on the underlying with strike $K$ such that:
$$
K < S_d < S_u
$$
I.e., an option that will surely be in the money. This (apparently, according to these notes: [http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/390/Lecture1.pdf](http://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/390/Lecture1.pdf)) violates the no-arbitrage assumptions of the model.

Question: What is the arbitrage opportunity here? It seems that if the option is expensive enough there will be no arbitrage.

Comment: Arbitrage will indeed depend on the price vs payoff, introducing this security might introduce redundancy but not necessarily an arbitrage if the price is right. Is K meant to represent the price of  the risk free bond?

Comment: $K$ here is the price at which the option is struck at, so we have a world where the option is in the money in all states.

Comment: Ok. It is an uninteresting case, but agree that it is not necessarily an arbitrage unless the option is cheap!

Comment: Got it - I've attached the set of notes where I read that this would lead to an arbitrage.

Comment: Ah I think it refers to 3 only where it says: Exercise: Show that if one of the inequalities (3) were violated then there would be an arbitrage.

Comment: I see - prior to that there's the statement that no one would sell the call if $K < d1$ or buy it if $K > d2$.